# r - plot outliers in kmeans plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-mining, outliers

i am trying to make an analysis using kmeans.

i have a dataset:

```
> head(data)

             tstamp   elementid     value hours
2016-09-15 15:20:28     IN_TEMP  25.12237    15
2016-09-15 15:20:29     IN_TEMP  25.44952    15
2016-09-15 15:20:29     IN_TEMP  25.53550    15
2016-09-15 15:20:39 IN_PRESSURE 101.40683    15
2016-09-15 15:20:49     IN_TEMP  25.94596    15
2016-09-15 15:20:49     IN_TEMP  25.38742    15
```

so i made this:

```
dataCluster <- kmeans(data[, 3:4], 2, nstart = 20)
dataCluster$cluster <- as.factor(dataCluster$cluster)
levels(dataCluster$cluster) <- c("IN_TEMP", "IN_PRESSURE")
ggplot(data, aes(value, hours, color = dataCluster$cluster)) + geom_point()
```

and the result is:
[image]

it is ok for my but when i make:

```
table(dataCluster$cluster, data$elementid)

             IN_PRESSURE | IN_TEMP
  IN_TEMP  |             0  |   953
  IN_PRESSURE |        508  |    44
```

I have 44 values on 2nd cluster that are IN_TEMP values (1st cluster).

Can i paint these 44 values with the color of the 1st cluster (red color) ?

Thanks by your help
Greetings

Comment: What's the point of the `kmeans` clustering in this analysis?

Comment: I have two kinds of data (Temperature and Pressure). Its obviously that i would create 2 clusters but i made this to show to my boss the idea of this algorithm :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i got it correctly, it's not the cluster label by which you want to color, rather you want to color by the variable elementid. You can simply use the following:

```
ggplot(data, aes(value, hours, color = elementid)) + geom_point()
```

Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scale_colour_manual` to set colors for clusters:

```
ggplot(...) + geom_point() + scale_colour_manual(values = c("red","red"))
```

see [scale_manual](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/scale_manual.html) for details.